# How to show product ratings from reliable sources in Magento?

Tags: magento, google-plus, rating, rich-snippets, review

I just saw on a competitors website that they had thousands of product ratings FROM Google+ showing that directly on their product page.

Normally this issue is about sending the ratings TO google using rich snippets, but what about the other way - getting the ratings? But without having sold them all yourself ? Is this really possible ?

First thought was this is must be a hoax - no way they could have so many reviews. But I researched it a bit more and realised that the reviews of the product does not have to be from ones own customers - but they have to be from "reliable sources". Well, THAT is changing the game quite a bit... :)

But, first - what is a "reliable source" - and how do I show those ratings on my product pages in Magento ?

If this is really true and an option this must be very good news for small business who have not yet achieved enough ratings and reviews to actually use it in their marketing.

Comment: Sounds like you need a standalone script that runs the search for reviews on google and picks up relevant info then saves it to a product attribute ;)

Comment: I would be surprised if I am the first and the only one thinking about this as an option to get product reviews/ratings a little bit easier than picking, writing and fishing for them myself from scratch.

What I am looking for is simply a Third part product Rating source and some code or even better a fixed extension to present and manage it.

Comment: I guess what I really mean here is NOT reviews - but only product ratings.